# Kiel oni povas mallongigi la vortojn „ŝalti/malŝalti“ aŭ „enŝalti/elŝalti“?

Tags: writing

Tiujn vortojn oni ofte uzas en komputilaj programoj kaj sur aparatoj. Jen ekzemploj en kelkaj lingvoj:

- *on/off* — angle. Mi pensas, ke tiuj vortoj estas mallongigoj de *turn on/turn off*;
- *включено/изключено* — bulgara. Oni ofte mallongigas tiujn tiel: *вкл./изкл.*, aŭ eĉ sen punktoj, tiel: *вкл/изкл*;
- *вкл/выкл* aŭ *вкл/откл* — rusa. (Tiuj estas mallongigoj, sed mi ne scias la longajn formojn de la vortoj.).

Ofte en komputilaj programoj mankas sufiĉe da spaco por skribi longajn vortojn. Kiel videblas en la supraj ekzemploj, lingvoj havas siajn manierojn mallongigi tiujn vortojn.

La esperantaj vortoj estas:

- *ŝalti(ta)/malŝalti(ta)* ; aŭ
- *enŝalti(ta)/elŝalti(ta)*

Sed ili povas esti tro longaj por uzi en limigita spaco (kaj la spaco ofte estas malgranda, ĉar la programistoj ofte ĝin faras sufiĉe granda por la anglaj vortoj, ĉar oni normale uzas la anglan kiel originalan lingvon). Ĉu ekszistas kutima maniero mallongigi ilin? Jen kelkaj ebloj, kiujn mi elpensis:

- *ŝ* / *malŝ*
- *ŝal* / *malŝ*
- *ŝ* / *mŝ*
- *enŝ* / *elŝ*
- *en* / *el* (Tio eble povas esti konfuza.)

Ĉu oni uzas iun el ili? Aŭ ĉu ekzistas alia kutima maniero mallongigi tiujn vortojn?

Answer (score 2):

Laŭ mi *en/el* plene taŭgas kaj pro la kunteksto ĝenerale ne estas dubsenca.

Mi renkontis ankaŭ *En ordo* kaj *Nuligu*, sed tio ja nur en iuj cirkonstancoj taŭgas.

Answer (score 1):

Vi povas uzo la Unikodajn simbolojn "POWER ON" ⏼ kaj "POWER OFF" ⏻ (Vidu ankaŭ http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2300.pdf )

Comment: Ne ĉiuij tiparoj enhavas tiujn simbolojn. Eĉ ĉi tie, en ĉi tiu retejo, mi ne povas ilin vidi en via komento… Sed ĉi tio estas bona ideo.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev: La simbolj estas novaj aldonoj al Unikodo 9.0. Literfontoj baldaŭ enhavos ilin.

Answer (score 1):

Eble uzu nombrojn: 1/0

Tio estas uzata eĉ en aliaj lingvoj se oni volas indiki ŝalteco aŭ malŝalteco de aparato.

Answer (score 1):

Se spaco ege mankas, vi povas uzi *Ŝ* kaj *MŜ*.

Tamen, pli kutimaj estas *EK* kaj *HALT*.

Answer (score 0):

En la esperanta, oni uzas la tutan vorton. Hodiaŭ, pli kaj pli en ĉiuj lingvoj, oni vidis bildojn anstataŭ vortojn.

[cdn.trendblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/android-power-button-not-working-cover@2x-620x400.png](http://cdn.trendblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/android-power-button-not-working-cover@2x-620x400.png)

Comment: Oni ne ĉiam povas uzi bildojn, bedaŭrinde. Sed ĉi tio estas bona ideo.

Comment: Ankaŭ bildoj ofte estas kulture specifaj, ne internaciaj.  Aŭ iuj uzas koloroj en bildoj kiel ruĝa/verda, kaj multaj homoj ne povas distingi inter tiuj du koloroj

Answer (score 0):

> Ofte en komputilaj programoj mankas sufiĉe da spaco por skribi longajn
>   vortojn.

Ne, ofte la grafika fasado estas malbone desegnita, sed vi maloftege mankas da spaco. Se vi vere mankas spacon, uzu simbolojn ("POWER ON" ⏼ kaj "POWER OFF" ⏻ aŭ bildoj) kaj doni al la uzantoj eblon koni la signifon rekte ekde la signo. Ekzemple uzu la "title" atributon en HTMLaj doiserojn.